# Cache locality when iterating through two container at the same time

Tags: c++, memory-management, cpu-cache

I got that, when doing some computations on each element of a container, the best performance is gained if the memory is contiguous.
But what if one have to work with two or more big containers (such that they won't fit completely the cache) at the same time?

```
int main()
{
    const std::size_t BIG_SIZE = 2000000;  // A number such that both ivec and fvec won't fit the cache

    std::vector<int> ivec(BIG_SIZE, 0);
    int start = 0;
    for (auto& i : ivec)
        i = start++;


    std::vector<float> fvec(BIG_SIZE, 0.f);


    auto iit = ivec.cbegin();
    auto fit = fvec.begin();
    for (; iit != ivec.cend() && fit != fvec.end(); ++iit, ++fit) 
        *fit = *iit * 3.14;  // What happens here?
}
```

In the last loop, will the cache load both the memory blocks near `*iit` and those near `*fit`, or will I miss the cache every time I access `*iit` and then `*fit`?

If the latter, should I customly allocate `ivec` and `fvec` with an interlaced pattern to prevent those misses?

Comment: There are several cache lines.

Comment: On a certain level, it all is very simple - every time you do read from memory, CPU prefetches (and postfetches) more than you actually read - the whole cache line is fetched. But more than one cache line exists in CPU, so reads from different memory addresses should populate different cache lines. I do not expect you to be penalized by this pattern, but it's always worth to verify with specialized tools.

Comment: Depends a great deal on *what* CPU you are using and what its memory/cache hierarchy looks like (some have no cache at all and there exist also NUMA architectures). Different CPUs also have different prefetch mechanisms and different cache eviction strategies. There's no "one true answer", it all depends on the hardware in question.

Comment: Thanks everyone, you were crystal clear. Just out of curiosity, how many lines are in a cache of a recent CPU?

Comment: **Which** CPU? It is very CPU specific.

Comment: A typical cache line is 64 bytes which would give a 32KB L1 cache 512 cache lines

Comment: "how many lines are in a cache of a recent CPU?" - Depends on the CPU. For some 0, for some many. 64 is somewhat common. What CPU are you targeting x86? x86_64?, Arm? Power? Sparc? Mips?, Other? How recent/what model? Cache associativity is also a factor, as is level of cache. Inclusive/exclusive? Victim cache only? It *depends*. It's all *very* hardware specific.

Comment: Ah it's really small, so one memory access will populate only one line at a time? I know that each CPU is different, but it's just to get an idea

Comment: One other thing that often matters *a lot* is your access pattern. Row major vs Column major. Most CPU prefetchers are really good at dealing with row major traversals, buf fall flat on their face when dealing with column major access patterns.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am targeting the most recent CPUs (x86_64 architectures), but I don't want to make tweaks that are too much hardware-dependent. I'm only trying to get an idea so that I can design a cache-friendly application. The last question I've in mind (the last, I promise): what if i had a container `std::vector<VeryBigClass>` in which `VeryBigClass` is bigger than a cache line? Will the nearby values be spread among more than one cache line or won't they be cached at all?

Comment: They will *probably* populate multiple cache lines. But again; it depends on the specific hardware, the size of `VeryBigClass`, the size and type of cache, the overall  system architecture (NUMA vs UMA), what other processes are running on that CPU, etc. Profiling and benchmarking (optimized builds) is what you ought to be doing.

Comment: Best advice I can give: Try to access data in a way that is friendly to your CPUs prefetcher. Try to minimize the size of objects accessed in critical paths. Try to avoid false sharing (look it up). Try to minimize context switches and other things that cause cache flushes. And benchmark, profile and test - *always* on optimized binaries, *never* on unoptimized debug builds.

Comment: https://youtu.be/WDIkqP4JbkE

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see what's faster is to benchmark. The answer will depend on: hardware, size of input, and other stuff (compiler, flags, etc.) However, for the purposes of this example, I will be using the website quick-bench.com with clang-6.0, C++17, -O3 and libstdc++. Here is the code for the comparison:

```
static void One(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    const std::size_t BIG_SIZE = 20000000;

    std::vector<int> ivec(BIG_SIZE, 0);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ivec);
    int start = 0;
    for (auto& i : ivec)
        i = start++;

    std::vector<float> fvec(BIG_SIZE, 0.f);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(fvec);

    auto iit = ivec.cbegin();
    auto fit = fvec.begin();
    for (; iit != ivec.cend() && fit != fvec.end(); ++iit, ++fit) 
        *fit = *iit * 3.14;
  }
}
BENCHMARK(One);

static void Two(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    const std::size_t BIG_SIZE = 20000000;

    std::vector<int> ivec(BIG_SIZE, 0);
    std::vector<float> fvec(BIG_SIZE, 0.f);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ivec);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(fvec);
    int start = 0;
    auto fit = fvec.begin();
    for (auto& i : ivec) {
        i = start++;
        *fit = i * 3.14;
        ++fit;
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Two);
```

The first function is your original code while the second function is a modified version. `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` simply prevents the two vectors from being optimized away. The results for an N of 2000:

[image]

The results for an N of 20000000:

[image]

As you can see, for large N, the second example suffers. You will need to craft your code carefully and conduct benchmarks, rather than making assumptions (Google benchmark is the underlying technology for quick-bench.com)

---

You can actually gain a performance boost by using the standard library functions. Presumably, this is because they've optimized for different scenarios and delegate to better code than you can optimize by hand. Here's an example:

```
static void Three(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    const std::size_t BIG_SIZE = 20000000;

    std::vector<int> ivec(BIG_SIZE, 0);
    std::vector<float> fvec(BIG_SIZE, 0.f);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(ivec);
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(fvec);
    int start = 0;
    auto fit = fvec.begin();
    std::iota(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 0);
    std::transform(ivec.begin(), ivec.end(), 
      fvec.begin(),
      [] (const auto a) {
        return a * 3.14;
      });
  }
}
BENCHMARK(Three);
```

We've replaced your hand-rolled loop with `std::iota` and `std::transform`. The results for large N:

[image]

As you can see, version 3 is faster (albeit marginally) than #1 and #2. So use standard library functions first, and only hand-roll it if it's too slow.

Comment: recommendation: Move `const std::size_t BIG_SIZE = 20000000;` somewhere both benchmarks can use it. Really sucks if you only change only one and then try to puzzle out why the benchmarks are radically out of line with the expectations. Hmmm. On re-read I'm not familiar enough with the benchmarking tool you are using to know if this is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thoroughly detailed answer, I’ve learnt very useful things about how to improve the performance. But I’m not sure I can mark it as the answer to the question, since the code I posted above is just an example to better understand how the cache works. The real answer is that the cache has multiple lines, thing I wasn’t aware of.